# mercurial forget revision changes to particular file

Tags: version-control, mercurial

In a recent commit I accidentally included changes to a settings file which had passwords and sensitive information for the production server. I pushed the changes to the private repository but there's also a public repository. I'd like to push the changes to the public repo but how can I avoid including the changes in that particular file from being included? It's already in the commit.

Comment: Rewrite history before push?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I pushed the changes to the private repository

Do you mean you committed the change-set locally, or you pushed it to another repo that only you have access to? Have you actually run `hg push`?

> but there's also a public repository.

Has the change-set made it to the public repo?

Basically if the change-set is public it's gone. It's out of your control. Change the credentials on the server.

If the change-set is still private, you may be in luck. If it's local then you can use `hg strip` to remove the change-set, but be warned it will also remove any descendants. If it's made it's way to any other repo, then you need to strip it from those too. If the change-set exists anywhere, then it'll come back when you `pull` from them.

Regardless, it's probably time to change the credentials on the server just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only *commit* (to your `.hg` repository) but not *pushed* to the default central repository, then you can use `hg rollback` which will "*undo*" your commit. You can then amend things: forget a file, do modifications, change the log message etc. then commit again and finally push.